# Manter o login ativo no flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Eu quero que quando o usuário faça login, mesmo encerrando a aplicação continue logado. Eu estou usando uma api própria feita em NodeJS. Pelas minhas pesquisas eu vi que dá pra fazer isso usando o plugin **SharedPreferences**. O problema é que não to conseguindo implementar isso no meu código.

Logo abaixo estão os códigos do login_bloc.dart e o login_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:localizamed_app/validators/login_validator.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import 'dart:convert';

//estados do login
enum LoginState {IDLE, CARREGANDO, SUCESSO, FALHA}

class LoginBloc extends BlocBase with LoginValidators{

  //controladores
  final _emailController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _senhaController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _stateController = BehaviorSubject<LoginState>();

  Stream<String> get outEmail => _emailController.stream.transform(validaEmail);
  Stream<String> get outSenha => _senhaController.stream.transform(validaSenha);
  Stream<LoginState> get outState => _stateController.stream;
  Stream<bool> get outSubmitValid => Observable.combineLatest2(
      outEmail, outSenha, (a, b) => true
  );

  Function(String) get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePassword => _senhaController.sink.add;

  //Login com a API
  Future<void> login() async{
    final email = _emailController.value;
    final senha = _senhaController.value;    

    _stateController.add(LoginState.CARREGANDO);

    String url = "http://192.168.0.200:8081/login";
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Accept": "application/json"};    

    try {
      http.Response response = await http.post(url,
        headers: headers,
        body: {          
          "email": email,
          "senha": senha
        });  
        if(response.statusCode == 201){
          _stateController.add(LoginState.SUCESSO);
        } else{
          _stateController.add(LoginState.FALHA);
        }

      } catch (erro){  

        print(_emailController);       
        return _stateController.add(LoginState.FALHA);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.close();
    _senhaController.close();
    _stateController.close();
  }  

}
```

---

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:localizamed_app/blocs/login_bloc.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:localizamed_app/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:outline_material_icons/outline_material_icons.dart';
//import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
//import 'package:passwordfield/passwordfield.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LoginScreenState createState() => LoginScreenState();

  final Stream<String> stream;

  LoginScreen({this.stream});
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _loginBloc = LoginBloc();

  bool invisible;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //estados de acordo com o que é retornado do Bloc -> API -> Banco
    _loginBloc.outState.listen((state) {
      switch (state) {
        case LoginState.SUCESSO:
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
          break;
        case LoginState.FALHA:
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Erro"),
                    content: Text(
                        "Sinto muito, mas seu E-mail/Senha estão incorretos!"),
                  ));
          break;
        case LoginState.CARREGANDO:
        case LoginState.IDLE:
      }
    });

    invisible = true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _loginBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    var size = mediaQuery.size;

    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<LoginState>(
            stream: _loginBloc.outState,
            initialData: LoginState.IDLE,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.data) {
                case LoginState.CARREGANDO:
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                          Color.fromARGB(255, 23, 29, 255)),
                    ),
                  );
                case LoginState.FALHA:
                case LoginState.SUCESSO:
                case LoginState.IDLE:
                  return SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      width: size.width,
                      height: size.height,
                      child:  SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: size.width / 3.1,
                                    top: size.height / 60),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text("LocalizaMed",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: size.width / 20,
                                        )),
                                    Image(
                                      image: AssetImage('images/pin.png'),
                                      width: size.width / 20,
                                      height: size.height / 20,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                              SizedBox(
                                height: size.height / 15,
                              ),
                              //label de BEM-VINDO
                              Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: size.height / 30,
                                      top: size.height / 30,
                                      right: size.width / 2,
                                      left: size.width / 15),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "Bem",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: size.width / 8,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "Vindo",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: size.width / 8,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            ".",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: size.width / 8,
                                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                                    .primaryColor),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )),

                              //campo de email
                              Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: size.width / 12,
                                      right: size.width / 20,
                                      top: 0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      StreamBuilder<String>(
                                          stream: _loginBloc.outEmail,
                                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                            return TextFormField(
                                              onChanged: _loginBloc.changeEmail,
                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  errorText: snapshot.hasError
                                                      ? snapshot.error
                                                      : null,
                                                  labelText: "E-mail"),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                                            stream: _loginBloc.outSenha,
                                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                              return TextFormField(
                                                onChanged:
                                                    _loginBloc.changePassword,
                                                obscureText: invisible,
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                    errorText: snapshot.hasError
                                                        ? snapshot.error
                                                        : null,
                                                    labelText: 'Senha',
                                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                                      icon: Icon(
                                                        invisible
                                                            ? Icons
                                                                .visibility_off
                                                            : Icons.visibility,
                                                        size: 20.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          invisible =
                                                              !invisible;
                                                        });
                                                      },
                                                    )),
                                              );
                                            }),
                                      ),

                                      //botão de ESQUECER A SENHA
                                      Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                        child: FlatButton(
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Esqueceu a senha?",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                                    .primaryColor,
                                                fontSize: size.width / 25),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: size.height / 50,
                                      ),
                                      //botão de LOGIN
                                      StreamBuilder<bool>(
                                          stream: _loginBloc.outSubmitValid,
                                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                            return RaisedButton(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    vertical: size.height / 55,
                                                    horizontal:
                                                        size.width / 3.29),
                                                color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                    255, 23, 29, 255),
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            23)),
                                                onPressed: snapshot.hasData
                                                    ? _loginBloc.login
                                                    : null,
                                                disabledColor: Colors.blue[300],
                                                child: Text("Login",
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        fontSize:
                                                            size.width / 25,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold)));
                                          }),

                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: size.height / 50,
                                      ),
                                      //botão de LOGAR PELO FACEBOOK
                                      Container(
                                        width: size.width / 1.4,
                                        child: RaisedButton(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: size.height / 55,
                                              horizontal: size.width / 8.4),
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(23),
                                              side: BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  width: 2)),
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Image(
                                                image: AssetImage(
                                                    'images/facebook_logo1.png'),
                                                width: 15,
                                                height: 15,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "Logar pelo Facebook",
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontSize: size.width / 28,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: size.height / 20,
                                      ),
                                      //Botão de se CADASTRAR
                                      Container(
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(
                                                "Não tem uma conta?",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: size.width / 25),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 1,
                                              ),
                                              FlatButton(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                                onPressed: () {},
                                                child: Text("Cadastre-se",
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                                            .primaryColor,
                                                        fontSize:
                                                            size.width / 25)),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                    )
                  );
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? 
Desde já agradeço ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences é uma das formas de se fazer, estou utilizando ela também em meu projeto.
Vou explicar utilizando o modelo que estou usando.

Crie uma classe só para manter as coisas no lugar `LocalSettings`

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LocalSettings{
  SharedPreferences preferences;

  Future<void> getInstance() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}
```

Para utilizar faça da seguinte forma:

```
class BlocThemes extends BlocBase {
  LocalSettings settings = LocalSettings();

  BlocThemes(){
    getInitialValues();
    _themeController.stream.listen((data){
      settings.preferences.setInt('theme', data.index);
    });
  }

  void getInitialValues() async{
    await settings.getInstance();
    if (settings.preferences.containsKey('theme'))
      inTheme.add(ApplicationTheme.values[settings.preferences.getInt('theme')]);
    else
      inTheme.add(ApplicationTheme.lightTheme);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _themeController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final BehaviorSubject<ApplicationTheme> _themeController = BehaviorSubject<ApplicationTheme>();
  Stream<ApplicationTheme> get outTheme => _themeController.stream;
  Sink<ApplicationTheme> get inTheme => _themeController.sink;
```

**Explicação**

> Para gravar valores

```
await SharedPreferences.getInstance().preferences.setInt('theme', data.index);
```

> Para pegar valores

```
await SharedPreferences.getInstance().preferences.setInt('theme', data.index);
```

**Aplicação no seu caso**

No momento que é feito a validação para saber se o usuário vai ser redirecionado para a tela de LOGIN ou para a HOME você testa da seguinte forma:

```
if (settings.preferences.containsKey('conectado'))
  if (settings.preferences.getBool('conectado'))
    HOME
  else
    HOME
```

Obs.: É claro que você deve fazer uma validação mais completa, esse é apenas um exemplo de uso.

Caso queria ver mais sobre, da uma olhadinha nesse meu projeto do GitHub [EquipmentMaintenance](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/EquipmentMaintenance)